# Get enum description from DB query data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, enums, dbcontext

I am getting data from DB and populating that in a model and returning that model.
My enum class:

```
  public enum ProcessEnum
{
    [Description("Done")]
    Done = 1,
    [Description("In Progress")]
    InProgress = 2,
    [Description("Pending")]
    Pending = 3,
}
```

Response model class:

```
     public class ReportsFilterModel
    {
        [Required]
        public ProcessEnum processStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

Method class:

```
 finalReports = await report
                    .Select(x => new ReportsFilterModel
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,
                        processStatus = (ProcessEnum)x.ProcessID
                    }).ToListAsync();
```

This returns me InProgess and I need the description i.e "In Progress".
This is just a snippet wheres there are a lot places I need the description of the enum.

Comment: can't you have a additional property that is decorated with `[NotMapped]` and that has the enum value in `ToString()` format

Comment: I'm trying `(ProcessEnum) x.ProcessID` or GetEnumDescription first, but I'm getting various type error

Comment: Should your processStatus at the class ReportsFilterModel not be ProcessEnum? -->   public class ReportsFilterModel
    {
        [Required]
        public ProcessEnum processStatus { get; set; }
    }

Comment: It is indeed ProcessEnum, I've corrected that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Display` attribute:

```
public enum MyColors
{
    [Display(Name = "Rot")] Red,
    [Display(Name = "Grün")] Green,
    [Display(Name = "Blau")] Blue
}

public enum MyAnimals
{
    Horse,
    Dog,
    Cat
}

public void DoThings()
{
    var enumList = new List<Enum>
    {
        MyColors.Red,
        MyColors.Green,
        MyColors.Blue,
        MyAnimals.Horse,
        MyAnimals.Dog,
        MyAnimals.Cat,
    };

    enumList.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e.GetName()));
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
    // print 'Display Name' if it exists, else print it's name as is.
    enumList.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.Name ?? "-"));
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
    enumList.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e.GetDisplayName()));
}
```

Output:

```
Red
Green
Blue
Horse
Dog
Cat
-------------------------------
Rot
Grün
Blau
-
-
-
-------------------------------
Rot
Grün
Blau
```

**Edit**: just realized, that i used a logger service class of my fiddle project. Replaced it with `Console.WriteLine`.